# Arrange width of column in DockPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dockpanel

I have a popup window that list all my warnings in the system.

The list is build like this:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <ItemsControl>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel>
                    <Image />
                    <TextBlock />
                    <TextBlock />
                </DockPanel>
            <DataTemplate>
        <...>
```

Image is hardcoded to have a Width of 16.

The last TextBlock is set to take all the remaining space with this property setted in my DockPanel:

```
LastChildFill="True"
```

How can I set my middle TextBlock to take only the space he needs?

Like a Width="Auto" ?

I need to keep, if possible, the structure with DockPanel

Thank you!

[image: Example]

Comment: You might be able to use a `Grid` instead and use [Grid.IsSharedSizeScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope.aspx)

Comment: Yes a grid might do the job but I need to do a quick fix and I don't want to change how it works, of course if it's possible...